# Can JS components inherit CSS style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am writing a web page. I have learned some react, as well as some basic html and css.
I was wondering, if DOM JS components can inherit css style from their parent? For example:

```
export default class Component extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div color="red">
      </div>
    );
  }
}

<div color="blue">
  <Component className={ /* my parents styles */} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your component cannot directly inherit classes from its parent but your parent can GIVE your component classes through its props.

```
<Component className="some-class" ...otherProps />
```

would result in:

```
<div class="some-class"></div>
```